# how do I determine in the parent component whether the rendering result of the child component is `null`

Tags: reactjs

I want to insert something between the content, but how do I determine in the parent component whether the rendering result of the child component is `null`?

https://codesandbox.io/s/k9nr4pqz9r

```
function LI({ show = true }) {
  if (show) {
    return <span>content</span>;
  }
  return null;
}

function UL({ children }) {
  let ret = [];
  React.Children.forEach(children, (child, index) => {
    if (true /* how to get child render result ? */) {
      ret.push(child);
      ret.push(" * ");
    }
  });
  if (ret.length) {
    ret.pop();
  }
  return ret;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <UL>
        <LI />
        <LI />
        <LI />
        <LI />
      </UL>
      <hr />
      <UL>
        <LI />
        <LI show={false} />
        <LI />
        <LI />
      </UL>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: The logic for something like that (is something true or false) should always belong to the Parent component/container.

Answer (score 0):

`ReactDOMServer.renderToString` allow you to get string HTML of the component. Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/20m61496zy

But I strongly don't recommend you to do this, since it costs a lot. A better solution for you is accessing `child.props` to read the condition ([demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ko2n9x5kz3)):

```
React.Children.forEach(children, (child, index) => {
    if ((typeof child.props.show === 'boolean' && child.props.show === false)) {
      ret.push(' nothing here ');
    } else {
      ret.push(child);
    }
    ret.push(" * ");
  });
```

Comment: The method of renderToString is very interesting. I feel that there is no good way.

Comment: To read what child component looks like after rendering is always costly, especially when the child component is complicated. Your `LI` is a simple one, so it might not be too obvious.

Comment: Reading child's props is more React-like. If you don't like that idea, then how about letting the child component `LI` handle prepend by itself?